# Pack js/css files and update references in jsp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to use gulp to implement this requirement: Pack js/css files and update corresponding references in jsp.

I have found [gulp-concat plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat/) to do the package work, **but I couldn't find the plugin to update corresponding references in jsp**.

I have found [gulp-hash-references plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-hash-references/) for [gulp-hash plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-hash/): "gulp-hash plugin" add hash postfix to js/css files names(e.g. test.js => test_93na86.js), while "gulp-hash-references plugin" updates corresponding references in html file(`<script src="test.js"></script>` => `<script src="test_93na86.js"></script>`).

So I wonder maybe there exists a plugin for [gulp-concat plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat/) like [gulp-hash-references plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-hash-references/) for [gulp-hash plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-hash/). Does a plugin of this kind exist? Or is there another way to fulfill my requirement?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have developed a [plugin](https://github.com/comcaptain/gulp-based-front-end-preprocessor) to meet my requirement.